# About the definition of lineal convexity

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables, convexity, several-complex-variables

I have been trying to understand the definition of lineal convexity. I am reading the article [Duality of functions defined in lineally convex sets](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.156.2879&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Christer O. Kiselman. For a set $A\subset \mathbb{C}^n\setminus \{0\}$ they have defined the *dual complement* and *lineal convexity* as follows.
[image] I have understood the definitions and also understood that $A$ is lineally convex iff $A=A^{**}$. But I haven’t used $A$ being a homogeneous set anywhere. Can anyone tell why in the definition is $A$ being homogeneous mentioned?

Also another reference to lineal convexity can be found in the book [Notions of convexity](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Notions_of_Convexity.html?id=VwspLw1XKRYC&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y) by Lars Hormander, page 290, is defined as [image: follows]

Comment: A non-homogeneous set cannot be linearly convex.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi But the symmetrized bidisc is non homogeneous, but it is linearly convex(also called hypoconvexity). See Theorem 2.3 here https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF02922097.pdf

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but suppose $A$ is not homogeneous and let $z \in A$ such that $tz \not \in A$ for some $t \neq 0$. Then how can there be a hyperplane passing through $tz$ not intersecting $A$? Since hyperplanes are homogeneous themselves, any hyperplane containing $tz$ must contain $z = \frac{1}{t} \cdot tz$, right?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Yes. You are correct. Well does it make a difference if we consider an affine Hyperplane instead of an hyperplane. Because that seems to be the difference between the two definitions. And they have used the affine Hyperplane definition in the Symmetrized bidisc paper.

Comment: Well, one book says "linea**l**ly convex" while the other says "linea**r**ly convex".